# How to test if a google analytics code works?

Tags: google-analytics

I made slight changes to the code described [here](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920) in order to track outbound link clicks. This is my code:

```js
function recordOutboundLink(link, label) {
  try {
    var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
    _gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', 'Outbound Links', label, link.href ]);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
  }catch(err){}
}
```

Then I added it to my href tags like so:

```html
<a href="http://example.com/user/5" onclick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'example.com');return false"></a>
```

I think it's not working, though. It's really hard to check if it works or not. How do I check if it's working or not?

EDIT: Using google analytics debugger for chrome I was able to see what's going on. It displays:

```
Account ID               : UA-XXXXX-X
```

It's odd because normal page tracking is working as expected. This is how I set up google analytics code:

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'my-id']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look for the `__utm.gif` tracking pixel request. A few different ways of doing this are:

- A web debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (my preference)
- The Network tab in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome Developer Tools.
- The Google Analytics debugging script [ga_debug.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#gaDebug) will log tracking requests & errors.
- [Google Analytics Tracking Code Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) is a Chrome extension that enables ga_debug.js.

The analytics code on the page probably has a _trackPageview, so as the page loads you'll see an initial __utm.gif.

When _trackEvent fires, there should be a new __utm.gif request being made. Parameters to examine in __utm.gif URL are:

- utme=5(Outbound Links*label*link.href) -- _trackEvent parameters
- utmac=UA-1234567-8 --  the analytics UID

Also, (as pointed out by [@Eduardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272031/eduardo)), take a look at [Google Analytics Basic Debugging](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#basicDebugging)

Comment: Also this one [gaTrackingTroubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#basicDebugging)

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome:

- Right Click anywhere on page
- Inspect Element
- Click Network Tab
- Reload Page

Look for:

- Type 'image/gif'
- Method: 'GET'
- Name (starts with): _utm.gif?

Comment: I can see it in my network stats. Does that mean my GA is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Using google analytics tracking code debugger which @mike pointed out I was able to figure out that, although http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920 tells us to use

```js
var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', 'Outbound Links', label, link.href ]);
```

does not longer work, and one should use

```js
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound Links', label, link.href ]);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [James for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/james/focgpljpblbfemgkcmgokbhafnddfdfn) it's simple and free, we wrote is to debug our internal tool but made it available to all

Comment: I think this is more suited to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to make sure that your tag is inserted in all of your pages. Here's a free service that can do that: http://www.tagcheckr.com
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this free chrome extension called [Trackie](https://github.com/pualien/Trackie)